# erlang string list concatenation

Tags: list, functional-programming, erlang, property-list

I have the following property list

```
PropList = [{numbers, ["22", "10"]}, {etc, "22"}].
```

I wish to get out the list `["22", "10"]` like this:

```
proplists:get_value(numbers, PropList).
```

The problem is that I get the two strings inside the list concatenated, ie `"2210"`. I tried using `propertylists:lookup/2` to get the whole numbers tuple and pattern match to extract the list. But I still end up getting `"2210"`.

I'm guessing it's because of the way erlang stores strings in memory.. Can someone help me here?

**Later Edit**: I've managed to extract and use the data if i do a map over the list of strings... Maybe this is just a printing issue?

**Later-Later Edit** I don't know what happened, maybe I'm too tired :) sorry guys. Will delete this question tomorrow

Comment: I copied and pasted and it works correctly (I get the array).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1> PropList = [{numbers, ["22", "10"]}, {etc, "22"}].       
[{numbers,["22","10"]},{etc,"22"}]

2> proplists:get_value(numbers, PropList).
["22","10"]

3>
```

That is my output with your given snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the code is correct. If you use `io:format`, it will concatenate all it can on output.

There is a meta-type in Erlang called `iolist` as in "can be used for input/output". It can be a list of characters (integers), other iolists or a binary. Sounds confusing, but quite handy.

If you want to pretty-print, use the `~p` format.

In other words:

```
2> io:format([[65, $B, 67], <<"DEF">>, [[71, 72], 73], "JKL", 10]).
ABCDEFGHIJKL
ok
3> io:format("~p", [[[65, $B, 67], <<"DEF">>, [[71, 72], 73], "JKL", 10]]).
["ABC",<<"DEF">>,["GH",73],"JKL",10]ok
```